Handling Touch event of multiple drawn model
I drew multiple texture vertexes, but i want to handle click event on each one of them using the vuforia sdk on IOS. I have saved the positions of each of the vertex and i have an event handler that is supposed to get the specific clicked vertex.
Vuforia Cloud Recognition Texture Tracking
During rendering
private func renderModel2(
        encoder: MTLRenderCommandEncoder?,
        vertices: MTLBuffer,
        vertexCount: Int,
        textureCoordinates: MTLBuffer,
        texture: MTLTexture,
        mvpBuffer: MTLBuffer,
        projectionMatrix: matrix_float4x4,
        modelViewMatrix: matrix_float4x4,
        scaledModelViewMatrix: matrix_float4x4,
        index: Int,
        numberOfColumns: Int,
        numberOfRows: Int,
        ySpacing: Float,
        xSpacing: Float,
        scale: vector_float3
    ) {
        let column = index % numberOfColumns
        let row = index / numberOfColumns
        let textureWidth = Float(texture.width)
        let textureHeight = Float(texture.height)
        
        var adjustedXSpacing = xSpacing
        var adjustedYSpacing = ySpacing

        let offsetX = -scale.x / 2 - (scale.x + adjustedXSpacing) * Float(column) + 0.28
        let offsetY = -scale.y / 2 + adjustedYSpacing * Float(row) + 0.2

        // Apply a higher z-index by adding a positive z-offset
        let zOffset: Float = 0.1 // Adjust this value as needed for correct depth ordering

        // Create translation matrix using simd_float4x4.translation
        let translationMatrix = matrix_float4x4(translation: SIMD3<Float>(offsetX, offsetY, zOffset))
        
        // Apply translation matrix
        let translatedModelViewMatrix = modelViewMatrix * translationMatrix

        let aspectRatio = textureWidth / textureHeight
        let viewScale = vector_float3(scale.x * aspectRatio, scale.y, scale.z)
        let scaledMatrix = matrix_float4x4(diagonal: SIMD4<Float>(viewScale.x * 0.9, viewScale.y * 0.9, viewScale.z * 0.9, 1.0)) // Reduce size by 10%

        // Combine translation and scaling matrices
        let modelMatrix = translatedModelViewMatrix * scaledMatrix

        // Update model-view-projection matrix
        var modelViewProjectionMatrix = projectionMatrix * modelMatrix
        mvpBuffer.contents().copyMemory(from: &modelViewProjectionMatrix.columns, byteCount: MemoryLayout<Float>.size * 16)

        // Set render pipeline state and buffers
        encoder?.setRenderPipelineState(mTexturedVertexShaderPipelineState)
        encoder?.setFragmentTexture(texture, index: 0)
        encoder?.setFragmentSamplerState(mWrappingSamplerState, index: 0)
        encoder?.setVertexBuffer(textureCoordinates, offset: 0, index: 2)
        encoder?.setVertexBuffer(vertices, offset: 0, index: 0)
        encoder?.setVertexBuffer(mvpBuffer, offset: 0, index: 1)

        // Draw primitives
        encoder?.drawPrimitives(type: .triangle, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: vertexCount)
        
        // Store the primitive's updated position and size
        let primitivePosition = SIMD3<Float>(modelMatrix.columns.3.x, modelMatrix.columns.3.y, modelMatrix.columns.3.z)
        overlayPrimitives[index].position = primitivePosition
    }

I currently do this on the vuforiaview.swift class but it doesn't work properly
 @objc private func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let tapLocation = sender.location(in: self)
    
        guard let currentFrame = accessFusionProviderPointers2().arFrame else {
            return
        }
        
        let convertTapToRaycast = currentFrame.raycastQuery(from: tapLocation, allowing:.estimatedPlane, alignment: .horizontal)
        let projectedLocationPoint = currentFrame.camera.projectPoint(convertTapToRaycast.origin, orientation: .portrait, viewportSize: self.bounds.size)
    
        let hitTestResults = currentFrame.hitTest(projectedLocationPoint, types: [.featurePoint])
    
        // Iterate over the hit test results
        for result in hitTestResults {
            var tappedPrimitive: MetalRenderer.Primitive?
            var minDistance = Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude
            var distances: [Float] = []
    
            for (index, primitive) in mRenderer.overlayPrimitives.enumerated() {
                let position = simd_make_float3(primitive.position.x, primitive.position.y, primitive.position.z)
    
                let worldTransform = result.worldTransform
                let worldPosition = worldTransform.columns.3
    
                let projectedLocation = simd_make_float3(Float(worldPosition.x), Float(primitive.position.y), Float(0))
                // Project the position to screen coordinates
                let projectedPoint = currentFrame.camera.projectPoint(position, orientation: .portrait, viewportSize: self.bounds.size)
                
    
                // Calculate the distance between the projectedPoint and projectedLocationPoint
                let dx = Float(projectedLocationPoint.x) - Float(projectedPoint.x)
                let dy = Float(projectedLocationPoint.y) - Float(projectedPoint.y)
                let distance = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
    
                // Store the distance in the temporary array
                distances.append(distance)
    
                // Check if the distance is within the primitive's bounding box
                let primitiveWidth = Float(primitive.size.width)
                let primitiveHeight = Float(primitive.size.height)
    
                let threshold: Float = 10.0 // Adjust this value as needed
                if distance <= max(primitiveWidth, primitiveHeight) / 2 + threshold && distance < minDistance {
                    minDistance = distance
                    tappedPrimitive = primitive
                }
                
            }
    
            // Find the index of the minimum distance
            let minDistanceIndex = distances.enumerated().min { $0.element < $1.element }?.offset
    
            if let index = minDistanceIndex, let primitive = mRenderer.overlayPrimitives[safe: index] {
                print("Tapped on primitive: \(primitive)")
                handleTapOnTexture(ui: primitive.ui)
            } else {
                print("No AR content tapped")
            }
        }
    }

